# PHP AWS Cognito 'Error executing "SignUp" : ResourceNotFoundException : User pool client XXXX does not exist

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

When i implement AWS Cognito in my project Occur following error.

```
Uncaught exception 'Aws\CognitoIdentityProvider\Exception\CognitoIdentityProviderException' with message 'Error executing "SignUp" on "https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"__type":"ResourceNotFoundException","message":"User pool client XXXX does not exist."} ResourceNotFoundException (client): User pool client XXXX does not exist. - {"__type":"ResourceNotFoundException","message":"User pool client XXXX does not exist."}' GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"__type":"ResourceNotFoundException","message":"User pool client XXXX does not exist."} in /vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/WrappedHttpHandler.php on line 191
```

I was used this URL: https://github.com/pmill/aws-cognito

This is my PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['action'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'] ?? '';
    $password = $_POST['password'] ?? '';

    if($_POST['action'] === 'register') {
        $email = $_POST['email'] ?? '';

        $error = $client->registerUser($username, $password, [
            'email' => $email,
        ]);

        if(empty($error)) {
            header('Location: confirm.php?username=' . $username);
            exit();
        }
    }}
```

This is config.php file.

```
$config = [
'credentials' => [
    'key' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    'secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
],
'region' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
'version' => 'latest',
'app_client_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
'app_client_secret' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
'user_pool_id' => 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'];

require './vendor/autoload.php';

$aws = new \Aws\Sdk($config);
$cognitoClient = $aws->createCognitoIdentityProvider();
$client = new \pmill\AwsCognito\CognitoClient($cognitoClient);
$client->setAppClientId($config['app_client_id']);
$client->setAppClientSecret($config['app_client_secret']);
$client->setRegion($config['region']);
$client->setUserPoolId($config['user_pool_id']);
return $client;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // use Aws\Exception\AwsException;
    
 // use Aws\CognitoIdentityProvider\CognitoIdentityProviderClient;

$awsCognitoClient = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',//Change with your region
    'credentials' => [
        'key'    => YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY,
        'secret' => YOUR_AWS_SECRET,
    ],
]);

try {
    $result = $awsCognitoClient->adminInitiateAuth([
        'AuthFlow' => 'ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
        'ClientId' => YOUR_APP_CLIENT_ID,
        'UserPoolId' => YOUR_USER_POOL_ID,
        'AuthParameters' => [
            'USERNAME' => $userName,
            'PASSWORD' => $password,
        ],
    ]);

    $arr = $result->toArray();
} catch (AwsException $e) {
    $errorArr = $e->toArray();
    $statusCode = $e->getStatusCode();
    $errorMessageCompleteLog = $e->getMessage();
}
```

That must give you the user information if success, if you get some error in the client, try making another client and during the creating process, there is a checkbox on the Cognito  where it says `Generate client secret`, uncheck the checkbox and use the new credentials.

Answer (score -2):

The error is thrown if the client id you are passing actually does not exist.
Maybe the user pool is created in a different region or configuration parameters are wrong